# É Possível Ver qual função Disparou Uma Exceção No Delphi

Tags: delphi

Bom dia

Estou fazendo uma central de exceção, quando acontece algum erro dispara uma mensagem com a classe do erro,  porém queria ver qual foi a ação que disparou a exceção, alguém sabe se é possível ?

Answer (score 3):

Sim, você consegue sim.

Tem uma tela chamada Call Stack(pilha de chamada), de acordo com a thread  de execução.

Apenas em  **`DEBUG MODE`**

Caso não esteja disponível você pode visualiza-la em:

**View > Debug Windows > Call Stack**

Nessa tela contém um rastro dos métodos anteriores e posteriores:

[image: Exemplo abaixo]